# Why is Filtergroup (-1) in Navision Page OR filtering on page level not working

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-al

Is it possible that filtering with an OR condition (using `FILTERGROUP(-1)`) isn't working on page level`?
and if so, why isn't it working?

I'am new to MS-Navision and i try to understand the underlining programming of it.
in MS-Navision Cronus-AG DB i created a Page based on the Customer Table. In the Customer Table i added two fields ( `Datefield Date` and `CodeField` Integer).  The created Page should only display Customers where `Datefield` OR  `codefield` is empty. I used two empty  Variables called

```
date Date 
codefield Code
```

I Tried to use the following Code in the `OnOpenPage`-Trigger:

```
 CLEAR(date);
 CLEAR(c20);
 
 FILTERGROUP(-1);
 SETFILTER(DateField, '%1', date);
 SETFILTER(CodeField20Old, '%1', c20);
 FILTERGROUP(0); // tried to remove this line, still not working
```

But no filter is set, especially not in the OR-Filter condition. How ever, if i use the same code snipped in a Codeunit, it is working the right way. And if i change `FILTERGROUP(-1)` to `FILTERGROUP(2)` a filter is set (with an AND-Condition).

Can anybode explain me this bevhavior?

Comment: That filtergroup was alway a little bit “hacky” and should not be used for filtering on pages I believe.

Comment: @MakSim filtergroups are a great way to hide filters on a page from the standard user.

Comment: @samga Well yes. In general it is what filtergroups are for. But not the `-1` one. My comment was referring to this only.

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be a direct anwser to your question, for your filtered record to show up in your page, you need to mark every single line and then only show the marked lines:

```
FILTERGROUP(-1);
SETFILTER(DateField, '%1', date);
SETFILTER(CodeField20Old, '%1', c20);

IF FindSet() then
  repeat
    Mark(true);
  until Next() = 0;

FILTERGROUP(0);
MarkedOnly(true);
```